# Oracle : SQL Command not properly ended for INTO clause

Tags: database, oracle

```
DECLARE
v_tax_types VARCHAR2(200);
vv VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
v_tax_types := ',rajat,dobriyal';
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM v_tax_types) FROM dual INTO vv ;
END;
```

This code gives me error :
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.
Pleas help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INTO` comes before `FROM`:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM v_tax_types) INTO vv FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, But dbms_output.put_line(vv); print blank . Why?

Answer (score 2):

As correctly said by the @Thorsten Kettner `INTO` must be placed at the correct location:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM v_tax_types) INTO vv FROM dual;
```

also, there is no need of `SELECT` statement, you can directly assign the value of the function to a variable as follows:

```
vv := TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM v_tax_types);
```

Comment: Thanks, But dbms_output.put_line(vv); print blank . Why?

Comment: @rajat: I don't know. It should work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba975c37e77266bfc6f8e97cd19e4806

Comment: "dbms_output.put_line(vv); print blank . Why?"   Hard to say, since there is no dbms_output command in any of the code you've shown.